# Python help to extract rows by column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I am looking to do is extract rows based on value in the "Code" column.  I am needing to create 5 different CSV files from each beginning file.  I will need 5 separate files when this is complete and the files will be: CC, Mortgage, HELOC, Auto, Other.

Here is a table showing which code numbers should go to each file.

| Code | Loan Type |
| --- | --- |
| 180, 302 | Auto |
| Mortgage | Mortgage |
| 303, 112 | HELOC |
| 126, 110 | CC |
| 201, 150, 262 | Other |

Here is a small sample of the Data File that I am needing to manipulate. This screenshot is substantially smaller than the full file.  The full file has 200k rows and 100ish columns.

I will also need to replicate this process for about 50 others files, as this is a monthly file and I have 4 years worth of data.

Not sure if it matters, but I do have pandas enabled on my computer inside VS code.

[Example of Data File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlBbu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to separate table into the structure you want:

```py
df_Auto = df.loc[df['Code'].isin([180,302])]
df_Mortgage = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["Mortgage"])]
df_HELOC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin([303,112])]
df_CC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin([126,110])]
df_Other = df.loc[df['Code'].isin([201,150,262])]
```

then you can save the files using `df.to_csv("FileName.csv")` function.

You use the following script to iterate over files you have and save the new csvs.

```py
file_names = ["file1", "file2"]

for i in file_names:
    # read the file 
    df= pd.read_csv(i+".csv")
    # if you need preprocessing 
    # ...
    # create new files
    df_Auto = df.loc[df['Code'].isin([180,302])]
    df_Mortgage = df.loc[df['Code'].isin(["Mortgage"])]
    df_HELOC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin([303,112])]
    df_CC = df.loc[df['Code'].isin([126,110])]
    df_Other = df.loc[df['Code'].isin([201,150,262])]
    
    # save files
    df_Auto.to_csv(i+"_Auto.csv")
    df_Mortgage.to_csv(i+"_Mortgage.csv")
    df_HELOC.to_csv(i+"_HELOC.csv")
    df_CC.to_csv(i+"_CC.csv")
    df_Other.to_csv(i+"_Other.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a go. Is there a way to rename the headers on the new files so I can make them match the headers of the DB table they will be going to.

Comment: Additionally, do I have to do one file at a time? Because I have a little over 50 of them that require this same thing..

Comment: You can use `listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')` to iterate over the files and save them. But if you want to save them in same file(as in one file will all auto trough out the 4 years of data) make use you dont save them over eachother. Open the file, concatinate them using `pd.concat` then save.

Comment: To rename the columns use the following `df=df.rename(columns = {'two':'new_name'})`

Comment: Thank you, I do not want them all in the same file. I am wanting to do them all in separate files so, 4 years of monthly data * 5 files for each month. I will give this a try in the morning, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I added a new script you can use to iterate over those files. Just change the list in there to your file names and it will save 5 new csv for each file you have

Comment: Hello Ahmet, if I wanted to use listoffiles = os.listdir('.') would I just replace that with "file_names"?  and then change line 3 to "for i in listoffiles" ?